# Old book series about time traveling. Had a game series too maybe?

Tags: story-identification

This is farfetched, but I'll try anyway.

I remember when I was a kid, I got a book that came together with a game. I am certain that this was before Windows XP, but not sure if it was DOS only or there was already Windows 95.

The hero possibly was a teenager, that went after an evil guy that kidnapped his girlfriend, and went back in time to save her.

One thing that I remember clearly is that when he traveled, he used "eternities" as a measurement. Like "Then after two eternities and a half I arrived". I am pretty sure it was a series for both games and books.

I can't tell how it ended because I played/read only the first one, and never managed to get the others.

The game was a action/plataform one, kinda like Flashback.

Since my memory is kinda blurry, I think but I am not certain it was translated to Brazilian Portuguese, unsure if only the book or both the book and the game

Comment: *cough* windows 3x *cough*. I'd be interested to see the answer for this though. I remember getting Planescape: Torment in a Game+Book deal and it really got me into the backstory so much more by letting my imagination picture it. Anyway Q: Can you remember what style of graphics it had? was it like mario style, or were the characters bigger on the screen? was it japanese style?

Comment: It was pixelated, and it played like Flashback/Out of this world(Or another world). I have a feeling that this game may be a game made in Brazil and not just translated, but I may be wrong. I asked my father about it(He plays too) and he said he vaguely remembers it too.

Comment: @Basya I knew it could be between Dos and Win95, but I couldn't put my finger on the exact timing. However now I've found it :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I cannot believe I've found it. My mistake was to look for it in english.

The series I was looking for is [Time Runners](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Runners)(Yes, it is ITALIAN and it looks like it doesn't have an english wikipedia article).

It was translated to Portuguese via Editora Abril.

[image: This image is familiar to me, which makes me think somehow I started from the third book]

I also found a description of the game here but here is the relevant plot:

> Episode 1 starts the adventure: we are introduced to the hero, Max,
>   his girlfriend Jessica and his friend, super-genius Lucas. At the same
>   time, in a distant future, the Skunks, intelligent robots who enslaved
>   the humans (mmmhhh... sounds original), lead by their king who calls
>   himself the Chronodemon, are going to invade various epochs using a
>   time travel device. Trouble starts when a similar machine made by
>   Lucas creates an interference, and a Gate opens in Jessica's house -
>   the stone in the ring that Max gave to her as a present, is of the
>   same type used by Skunks for time Travel. The robots kidnap Jessica.
>   Lucas puts a time travel device on a scooter, and Max uses it to start
>   the risky rescue of his beloved one, ending up in the prehistory,
>   where he will find some allies...

The italian version had 30 parts. I've [found a mention](http://pararobo.blogspot.com/2016/01/time-runners.html) that it was canceled on the 11th chapter, but I cannot confirm. All I can tell is that I can only find up to a Time Runners 8 in portuguese, but this has the "Final battle" title, so I am unsure if they compiled the versions together.

For more info about the game instead of the books, [I've found this review of it](https://www.old-games.com/download/2995/time-runners-1), and also this gameplay:

<sub>I've found this by doing the opposite of usual ID questions. Instead of looking for the story details(that were blurry) I went and looked for who translated things to Portuguese in the 90's. Then I tried looking for the list of published things from them at that time. I went through the catalog from Brasoft first(Which wielded nothing) and then I found this forum post from 2008 with a "List of games Officially released in portuguese", where I saw Time Gate, and then the winner, Time Runners</sub>

Comment: Excellent! Don't forget to accept is in another 31 hours. :)

Comment: The music hurts my ears. Was this acceptable back then?

Comment: It was, somehow.